# Image of fundamental group under induced homomorphism normal

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am preparing for my topology exam and going through some exercises in Munkres. This is section 79 problem 3:

Let $p : E \to B$ be a covering map; let $p(e_0) = b_0$. Show that $H_0 = p_∗(\pi_1(E, e_0))$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(B, b_0)$ if and only if for every pair
of points $e_1$, $e_2$ of $p^{−1}(b_0)$, there is an equivalence $h : E \to E$ with $h(e_1) = e_2$.

For anyone not familiar with Munkres' notation:

- $p_*$ stands for induced homomorphism and for any pointed continuous map  $h: (X, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)$ carrying $x_0$ to $y_0$, it is defined as map: $$h_∗ : \pi_1(X, x_0) \to \pi_1(Y, y_0)$$
  such that:
  $$h_∗([ f ]) = [h \circ f ]$$
- What he refers to as equivalence is just a deck or a covering transformation, i.e. a homeomorphism $h: E \to E$ such that $p = p \circ h$.

I am interested only in the backward direction of the proof i.e. showing that the subgroup is normal under  the given assumptions. However I don't really know where to start from and how to use this condition of covering transformation that was given to me.

If I unpacked the definitions correctly, I think I have to obtain that for any $[f] \in \pi_1(E, e_0)$ and any $[g] \in H_0$ the following holds:
$$[g] * [p \circ f] = [p \circ f] * [g]$$
I assume that at some point I will have to lift these loops in $B$ to paths in $E$ and then somehow use the given condition but I am not sure how.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show that for all $\gamma \in \pi_1(B,b_0)$ and all $\chi \in H_0$ one has $\gamma ^{-1} \chi \gamma \in H_0$ (**not** $\gamma \chi = \chi \gamma$ as you write).

With your notation this means
$$[g]^{-1} * [p \circ f] * [g] \in H_0. $$

Let us lift the loop $g^{-1} * (p \circ f) * g$ in $B$ to $E$. Take the unique lift $\tilde g$ of $g$ such that $\tilde g(0) = e_0$. This is a path in $E$, but not necessarily a loop in $E$. Let $e_1 =  \tilde g(1)$.  The path
$$F = \tilde g^{-1} * f * \tilde g$$
is a loop based at $e_1$.

Let $h : E \to E$ be a deck transformation such that $h(e_1) = e_0$. Then $h \circ F$ is a loop based at $e_0$, i.e. $[h \circ F] \in \pi_1(E,e_0)$. We get
$$p_*([h \circ F]) = [p \circ h \circ F] = [p \circ F] = [(p \circ \tilde g^{-1}) * (p \circ f) * (p \circ \tilde g)] = [g^{-1} * (p \circ f) * g] \\= [g]^{-1} * [p \circ f] * [g]$$
which means that
$$ [g]^{-1} * [p \circ f] * [g] \in H_0 .$$

Comment: I assume $F = \overline{g}^{-1} * f * \overline{g}$ (instead of composed)?

Comment: @AlaskaYoung Yes, it was a typo. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the notion of regular covers? Some authors call them normal covers. If for any two elements points $e_1,e_2 \in p^{−1}(b_0)$ there exists a deck transformation $h$ so that $h(e_1) = e_2$, then $E$ is a regular cover, i.e. $p_*(E) \approx \pi_1(E,e_0)$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(B,b_0)$.

In other words: If $E$ is a regular cover of $B$, the deck group of $E$ acts transitively on fibers $p^{−1}(b)$ (for all $b\in B$).

So the idea is that changing basepoints in the cover $E$ corresponds to conjugating the subgroup $\pi_1(E,e_0)$ by an element $g$ of $\pi_1(B,b_0)$. This implies that $g$ is in the normalizer of the subgroup $\pi_1(E,e_0)$ if and only if the subgroup $\pi_1(E,e_0)$ is normal.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with this concept. Is there any more elementary way of showing it?